# stochastic domination in a probability space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega$ be a space and let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be two probability measures.  Assume that for a family of subsets of $\Omega$,
$(A_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$, 
$P_1(A_i ) \geq P_2(A_i)$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Is it true that, for any finite union of events $A_i$, $\bigcup A_i$, we have that $P_1 (\bigcup A_i ) \geq P_2 (\bigcup A_i)$? If not, what would be the counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true.

Let it be that $P_{1}\left(A\right)=P_{2}\left(A\right)$, $P_{1}\left(B\right)=P_{2}\left(B\right)$,
$P_{1}\left(A\cap B\right)>0$ and $P_{2}\left(A\cap B\right)=0$.

Then:

$$P_{1}\left(A\cup B\right)=P_{1}\left(A\right)+P_{1}\left(B\right)-P_{1}\left(A\cap B\right)<P_{2}\left(A\right)+P_{2}\left(B\right)=P_2(A\cup B)$$

Based on this you can build a counterexample by taking $A_1=A$, $A_2=B$ and $A_n=\varnothing$ for $n>2$.